# How to Install automatically PE agents in different Nodes?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I am new in Puppet.

I am done for installing PE Master.

I am done for install and setup Two PE agents.

My question is how to automatically install PE Agents in different Nodes or Virtual machines.

I know using answers.txt file you can install PE agents in new nodes.

But, without answers.txt file install PE agents.

Please, help me

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: What is your detailed problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Installing PE Agents automatically in diff. Nodes using Shell Scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet does configuration management well, but it is not so great at provisioning. For this you will almost certainly need another tool, such as [Foreman](http://theforeman.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Puppet Package Mangement`

From the node:

```
 curl -k https://<master hostname>:8140/packages/current/install.bash | bash
```

Then just sign the cert on the master once completed:

```
 puppet cert list
 puppet cert sign <certname>
```

#### Reference

https://puppet.com/docs/pe/latest/installing_pe.html#installing-agents-using-pe-package-management